# How to add a timer to the program?

Tags: while-loop, timer, haar-classifier

So the goal is by using openCV with python, constantly monitor the eyes and if the program fails to detect eyes then it would sound an alarm. The primary issue I am currently having is the fact that I need some sort of timer to delay the program so that the alarm does not trigger after only blinking. The program runs on a constant While loop as it updates frame by frame by the camera and when I use time.sleep(), the entire program halts. Perhaps, I do not need a timer but rather some sort of threshold, I don't know. Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Python, in which case you could take advantage of the time module as follows-

```
import time

while (condition):
    t = time.time
    if (eyes_not_detected and time.time - t > max_time):
        alarm()
```